# C# selenium load html

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to load html from `WebClient()` to selenium driver.
I have:

```
 WebClient glavniklijent = new WebClient();
 string HTML = glavniklijent.DownloadString("http://www.bodum.com/gb/en-us/shop/detail/10948-01/");
```

If I save it like local html file and then navigate on it

```
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(localfile);
```

It wont help because then it will request online resources. Which take too long.

Also I tried with Javascript Executor

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
            string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("document.write('" + HTML +"')");
```

But that don't work.

**Reason why I do this is** For me easiest way for parsing html is with Selenum driver, I tried with `HtmlAgilityPack` but I never used it before and it seems much complicated compared with Selenium Select By Id, Select by classname etc.

Can I load this with selenium locally ? 
Is there html parser similar to selenium ?

Answer (score 0):

Try CsQuery

https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery

https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsQuery/

It makes parsing HTML pretty easy, in a way very similar to jQuery:

```
var document = CsQuery.CQ.CreateDocument(html);
foreach (var element in document.Select("ul.somelist > li.thread")) 
{
    // do something with element
}
```